# Define example input in Swagger for post-request

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I use a DTO for my rest service in SpringBoot like this:

```
private int id;   
private String name;   
private int phone;
//get and set
```

In my controller class, I define Swagger anotation like this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Create a new person", response = personDTO.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Successful operation", response = personDTO.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Server error")})

    @PostMapping("person")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<personDTO> createPerson(@RequestBody personDTO person);
```

The Swagger documentation shows an example input a json with *id*, *name* and *phone* based on the DTO.

It is possible to remove the "id" from the example? The value is auto incremented by the database, and should be given as input in the post-call..

Is it also possible to specify example values? F.example that the example is

`{ 
"name":"Mike", 
"phone":"12345" 
}`

Comment: Did my provided solution resolve you query ? Were you able to achieve the desired result ? Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ApiModelProperty` in your DTO against the property:

## For hiding:

```
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
```

## For example value:

```
@ApiModelProperty(example = "Sam")
```